# Load JSF page by id

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF 2.0 app where each page is stored in a cms_page table in the database. That table has the PK column cms_page_id and a URL column (which holds the SEO friendly URL).

When I display a page there is a link called About Us, which has the URL "/com/aboutus.html"
This appears in my XHTML file as:
#{cmsPage.cmsPageUrlName}/>

Which renders
`<a href="/com/aboutus.html">About Us</a>`

As far as I know h:outputLink cannot be used to fire any methods in the backing bean.
I can't use h:commandLink, as this will not show the "/com/aboutus.html" URL when you hover over the link. I can't figure out how to fire a backing bean method to navigate to the next page.
The about us link would really be going to /faces/pages.xhtml, but would use PrettyFaces to display the "/com/aboutus.html" URL

Also, what would I to if I went directly to the URL `www.test.com/com/aboutus.html`?
This URL doesn't exist, the actual URL would be `www.test.com/faces/pages.xhtml?url=%2Fcom%2Faboutus.html`
Should I be looking at setting up PrettyFaces to do all the work instead?

Answer (score 0):

1. create Databaseconnection
2. read column from the database
3. write the column into your jsf page

please take a look at JSF/JPA documentations or tutorials to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ui:include src="#{cmsPage._url}" />
```

ManagedBean Name

```
@ManagedBean(name="cmsPage")
@SessionScoped
class Cms_Page{
  private String _pageId;
  private String _url;

  //getter setter
}
```

Use Custom method to fetch from DAO and set the values inside Cms_Page

Comment: I understand what you are doing here, but when the page loads, the URL would be the (for example) /faces/page.xhtml

Comment: That your welcome page but you can redirect the page you want after getting the value from the DB.

Comment: I updated the description. I need to know how you fire a backing bean method using only h:outputlink

Comment: Have a look at the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink